# Text box forgets text over long period of typing

Tags: php

hi guys I have a text box and when I submit what ever in the text box it tends to submit okay with no problems at all

the problem is that when I submit the text box with text that has taken let's say 15 minutes to type, once submitted it would say the box is empty but if I go back copy paste the text I had wrote and re submit it would submit.

How do I make it that text will be remembered so anyone who typing out a blog lets say or something similar that takes a bit of time to type out can still submit the content without any problem?

this is my form:

```
    <form method=POST action=http://www.//.com/hottopix.php?action=topicpost&who=$messageboard[id]>
<input type='hidden' name='token' value=";

echo $_SESSION[token];

echo " />
<div align=center>
    <table border=0 width=66% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
    <tr>
        <td width=18>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
        <table border=0 width=881 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor=#008000 width=881>
                <table border=0 width=100% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
                    <tr>
                        <td height=2 width=4></td>
                        <td height=2></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=4></td>
                        <td><b><font size=2>Topic Title</font></b>
                                            <input type=text name='topic' size=103 maxlength=250 style='outline: none; overflow: hidden; border: none'></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td height=2 width=4></td>
                        <td height=2></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor=#C0C0C0 width=881>
                <table border=0 width=881 cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=5></td>
                        <td width=10></td>
                        <td width=881><b><font size=2>Article</font></b></td>
                        <td width=10>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=5></td>
                        <td width=881>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                        <td width=881>
                        <table border=0 width=87% cellspacing=0 cellpadding=0>
                            <tr>
                                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                <td>
                                <p align=center>
                                <textarea type=text name='topiccontent' cols=107 rows=21 style='outline: none; overflow: hidden; border: none'></textarea></td>
                                <td width=4>&nbsp;</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        </td>
                        <td width=881>
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width=5></td>
                        <td width=10></td>
                        <td width=881>
                        <p align=right>
                        <input type=image name=submit0 src=http://www.//.com/commentpost2.jpg value=send border=0 ></td>
                        <td width=10></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </td>
        <td width=4>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

that is my text box form above. below is the code for when it is submitted. The session token in case anyone is wondering is there for no double posting which works perfectly fine.

```
    if ($_POST['topiccontent'] == "") {

echo "<p align=center>Sorry your Topic was not posted due to the Article section being blank. You will be redirected in a few seconds so please try again</p>
include("bottom.php");
exit;
}

if ($_POST['topic'] == "") {

echo "<p align=center>Sorry your Topic was not posted due to the Topic Title being blank. You will be redirected in a few seconds so please try again</p>
include("bottom.php");
exit;
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token']))
{
    if (isset($_POST['token']))
    {
        if ($_POST['token'] != $_SESSION['token'])
        {

echo "<p align=center><b>Bit of a problem here, Double Post attempt has been found. Don't worry we stopped it.</b></p>";
        }
        else
        {

$forumcount = $row[forum] + 1;
$forumweek = $row[forumweek] + 1;

$con=mysqli_connect(connection stuff here)

 if (mysqli_connect_errno())
   {
   echo "<p align=center>Failed to connect to MySQL: </p>" . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

 $sql="INSERT INTO forumtopic (topic, content, category, userid, username, date)
 VALUES
 ('$_POST[topic]', '$_POST[topiccontent]', '$who', '$row[id]', '$row[name]', '$today')" or die(mysql_error());

 if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
   {
   die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
   }
```

So we have no problems here at all it just stops at my statement for if CONTENT is blank and that error message shows.

Like I said it does not do this if you type something else in the matter of seconds but if you take time to write something out like an essay like this post it will say the text box is empty, though copy and paste what you have typed back into the text box and resubmit it will work fine.

So why is it timing out on the text box data? how do I stop this from happening?

Comment: sessions timming out ?

Comment: You are probably experiencing a session timeout. Check this page: http://prajapatinilesh.wordpress.com/2009/01/14/manually-set-php-session-timeout-php-session/

Comment: if were on about Session Token then no it shouldn't be as session token is defined as `$_SESSION['token'] = md5(session_id() . time());` this is just so we can tell if there is a double post or not

Comment: could it be a break down of as we can see my ECHO $_SESSION[TOKEN] is briefed as that but later on in the next statement it is known was $_SESSION['TOKEN'] could this be something that is conflicting and stopping the data transfer?